# Add class to all elements with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit new to javascript and jquery, and I have some troubles doing what I want in a "nice" way.

I have a HTML web page like this:

```
<div class="list-group">
   <a href="#all" id="category-all" class="list-group-item active">All</a>
   <a href="#" id="category-0" class="list-group-item">Foo</a>
   <a href="#" id="category-1" class="list-group-item">Bar</a>
   <a href="#" id="category-2" class="list-group-item">FooBar</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="category-0">element 1</div>
   <div class="category-1">element 1</div>
   <div class="category-1">element 1</div>
   <div class="category-0">element 1</div>
   <div class="category-2">element 1</div>
   <div class="category-0">element 1</div>
   <div class="category-2">element 1</div>
</div>
```

I would like to add some kind of "filter", where if you click on a certain category link, all elements from other categories will disappear.
I managed to do it by adding a class to my css called invis with "display:none", and then wrote this:

```
$( ".list-group-item" ).click(function() {
  $(".list-group-item").removeClass('active');
  $( this ).toggleClass("active");
  var test = "." + event.target.id;
  $(".category-0").addClass('invis');
  $(".category-1").addClass('invis');
  $(".category-2").addClass('invis');
  if (test == ".category-0")
    $(".category-0").removeClass('invis');
  if (test == ".category-1")
    $(".category-1").removeClass('invis');
  if (test == ".category-2")
    $(".category-2").removeClass('invis');
  if (test == ".category-all") {
    $(".category-0").removeClass('invis');
    $(".category-1").removeClass('invis');
    $(".category-2").removeClass('invis');
  }
});
```

This does the job, but I'd like to find a "cleaner" way of doing it. How can I improve it?

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it using jQuery would be to hide all of the `<div>`s when a filter control is clicked, then unhide the specific ones that you want to show.

This way you won't need your extra `invis` class.

***you will notice the "^=" symbol in the below code it simply is a selector that literally means "starts with".***

```js
$('a[id^="category"]').click(function() {
// when an <a> element is click THAT has an ID that starts with "category" ...

  $('div[class^="category"]').hide();
  // hide every <div> that's ID starts with "category" ...
  $('div.' + this.id).show();
  // re-show every <div> that's CLASS matches the original <a>'s ID ...
});
$('a[id="show-all"]').click(function() {
  // if the "all" is clicked, show them ALL again.
  
  $('div[class^="category"]').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#all" id="show-all" class="list-group-item active">All</a>
  <a href="#" id="category-0" class="list-group-item">Foo</a>
  <a href="#" id="category-1" class="list-group-item">Bar</a>
  <a href="#" id="category-2" class="list-group-item">FooBar</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="category-0">Foo</div>
  <div class="category-1">Bar</div>
  <div class="category-1">Bar</div>
  <div class="category-0">Foo</div>
  <div class="category-2">FooBar</div>
  <div class="category-0">Foo</div>
  <div class="category-2">FooBar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hide all elements with class "row" and then un-hide all elements with class [id of what was clicked] within class "row".

```
$('.list-group-item').click(function(event) {
  $('.row').addClass('invis');
  $('.row.' + event.target.id).removeClass('invis');
});
```

Comment: Guys, format your code. No empty spaces, use single quotes, etc. =)

Comment: Why use single quotes, @Geuis?

Comment: @Godisgood Is a better style. Since a lot of time in js you're dealing with html in strings, you generally want to use double quotes in html and single quotes in javascript. So when you're concatenating strings containing html code and javascript, its a lot easier to deal with escaping and things.

Comment: Thanks, got it working with a few edits.

Comment: as is, wouldnt this hide and show the container div the OP is using and not the inner category divs the OP wants to manipulate. I suspect this is one of the edits the OP commented on

Comment: Yeah, all my elements have another "styling" class (<div class="style category-x">), so instead of "row" I used "style" so that it wouldn't hide the whole container.

Answer (score 1):

By simply **adding to all your categories** the `.category-all` you've done half-job.
Now you can control the `id`>>>`class` relations much easily.

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/badayo/3/edit)***

If you need to always have at least one category visible it's quite simple:

```
var $btns = $(".list-group-item");
var $ctgs = $("[class^='category-']");
$ctgs.addClass("category-all");                         // Job done! :D :D

$btns.click(function(e) {
  $ctgs.hide();                                         // Hide all
  $("."+this.id).show();                                // Show realated
});
```

---

Otherwise, The code below will allow you to have any combination you desire
And even hide/toggle the active ones:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/badayo/2/edit?html,css,js,output)***

```
var $btns = $(".list-group-item");
var $ctgs = $("[class^='category-']");
$ctgs.addClass("category-all");                         // Job done! :D :D


$btns.click(function(e) {    
  $ctgs.not("."+this.id).hide();                        // Hide all (not this...)
  $("."+this.id).toggle( $(this).hasClass("active") );  // Toggle realated
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: not tested.

```
$('.list-group-item').click(function() {
    $('.list-group-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id == 'category-all') {
        $('div.row > div').show();
    } else {
        $('div.row > div.' + id).show();
        $('div.row > div:not(.' + id + ')').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another version. Added color coding for visibility.
*Edit updated to actually have the right behavior.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPrGJp

```
$( ".list-group-item" ).click(function() {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.row > div').show();
  $('.' + $(this).attr('id')).hide();
});
```

Comment: it still does not work on the `ALL` button